# Align Image div at the bottom of the outer div

Tags: html, css

Can somebody look at this CSS and tell me on how can i align Image div for 'Get Now' button to the bottom of the outer div.

Please look at the html code at the link below.

http://us2.campaign-archive2.com/?u=d00f22f51a6b4656c994333b9&id=6e343ae8a2&e=99b2a3de42

Comment: please provide relevant code here.

Comment: You have invalid markup.  Multiple elements with the same ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following line:

```
#link-button-image a {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5px;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

Comment: My Bad replied before even testing. This solution doesn't work on email clients like gmail and yahoo. They still show the button misaligned. Although it looks good in browser.

Comment: Any guess on why it doesn't work on mail clients like yahoo and gmail

Answer (score 0):

Set a `min-height` on the `<span>` that contains the offer text, `50px` works quite well.